# Fetch a custom Product Option from the title

Tags: magento2, custom-options

I made a custom option from the admin for a product and set a title for the option. However when I programmatically fetch all the options for that product the attribute is identified by a code which is "option_1" and the title is no where to be found.

Is there a way to fetch this option by the title that I set or at least access the title from the option object?